# How to evaluate this integral ($\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\alpha x^2)\cos(\beta x)dx$)?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am facing issue to evaluate this particular type of definite integral,

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\alpha x^2)\cos(\beta x)dx$$

Please suggest a way to this.

Thanks

Comment: This is just a Fourier transform of $e^{-\alpha x^2}$

Comment: This is similar to Fourier transform. For a gaussian, the F.T. is also a gaussian.

Comment: Why has this question been put on hold? It has sparked a number of good solutions which will undoubtedly help many viewers. A question like this is what makes MSE interesting, informative, and enjoyable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I(\alpha,\beta)$ be given by the integral

$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\cos(\beta x)\,dx$$

Using Euler's Formula, $\cos(\beta x)=\text{Re}(e^{i\beta x})$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha,\beta)&=\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}e^{i\beta x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha (x^2-i(\beta/\alpha) x)}\,dx\right)\tag 1 \\\\
&=e^{-\beta^2/4\alpha}\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha (x-i(\beta/2\alpha) )^2}\,dx\right)\tag 2\\\\
&=e^{-\beta^2/4\alpha}\text{Re}\left(\int_{-i(\beta/2\alpha)}^{\infty-i(\beta/2\alpha)} e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx\right) \tag 3\\\\
&=e^{-\beta^2/4\alpha}\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx\right) \tag 4\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4\alpha}}e^{-\beta^2/4\alpha}
\end{align}$$

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we completed the square in the exponent.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we enforced the substitution $x\to x+i\beta/2\alpha$.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we exploited Cauchy's Integral Theorem to deform the contour back to the real line.  The real part operation nullifies the contribution from the integral from $-i\beta/2\alpha$ to $0$.

Comment: But the Euler's formula, I know is $\cos(\beta x) = \frac{\exp(i\beta x)+\exp(-i\beta x)}{2}$. How come $\cos(\beta x)=\text{Re}(e^{i\beta x})$?

Comment: @mmm Yes, you are correct.  And $e^{i\beta x}=\cos(\beta x)+i\sin(\beta x)$ from which we find $\cos(\beta x)=\text{Re}(e^{i\beta x})$.

Comment: If I am correct the (3) to (4) is to use $\oint\limits_{C}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{R}f(z)dz$?

Comment: The integrand is entire, so $\oint_C e^{-\alpha z^2}\,dz=0$.  Thus, with $C$ the "rectangular" contour with vertices $0$, $\infty$, $\infty-i\beta/2\alpha$, and $-i\beta/2\alpha$, we have $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\,dx+\int_{\infty}^{\infty -i\beta/2\alpha}e^{-\alpha z^2}\,dz+\int_{\infty -i\beta/2\alpha}^{-i\beta/2\alpha}e^{-\alpha z^2}\,dz+\int_{-i\beta/2\alpha}^0 e^{-\alpha z^2}\,dz=0$$The second integral is zero since $e^{-t^2}\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. The fourth integral is purely imaginary since $dz=idy$ and vanishes upon taking the real part.

Comment: Thanks dear. Now I completely understand the whole process.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}e^{i\beta x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha\left(x-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\int_{-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}}^{\infty-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}}e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\left[\int_{-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}}^0e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm{d}x+\color{#A0A0A0}{\int_\infty^{\infty-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}} e^{-\alpha x^2}\mathrm{d}x}\right]\tag{3}\\
&=e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\left[\,\color{#D080F8}{i\int_0^{\frac\beta{2\alpha}}e^{\alpha x^2}\mathrm{d}x}+\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi\alpha}\,\right]\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: complete the square
$(2)$: substituted $x\mapsto x+i\frac\beta{2\alpha}$
$(3)$: the integrand is entire; apply [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)
$(4)$: the integral over $\left[R,R-i\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right]$ vanishes

The integral in purple is pure imaginary, so taking the real parts of $(4)$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\cos(\beta x)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac12e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\sqrt{\frac\pi\alpha}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: See the answer I wrote, in my opinion the identity theorem is easier to understand than the Cauchy integral theorem when you don't know so much of complex analysis

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}} \cos(bx) \mathrm{d}x
\tag{1}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

Let
\begin{align}
I_{1} &= \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}} \mathrm{e}^{ibx} \mathrm{d}x
= \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}+ibx} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \mathrm{e}^{-b^{2}/4a} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-a(x-ib/2a)^{2}} \mathrm{d}x \\
\tag{2}
\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
Here we completed the square and note that $\mathrm{Re}\,I_{1} = I$.

Consider the indefinite integral
\begin{align}
\int \mathrm{e}^{-a(x-ib/2a)^{2}} \mathrm{d}x
&= \int \mathrm{e}^{-ay^{2}} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int \mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}} \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \mathrm{erf}(z) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \mathrm{erf}\left(x\sqrt{a} - \frac{ib}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)
\tag{3}
\label{eq:3}
\end{align}
we used the substitutions, $y=x- \frac{ib}{2a}$ and $z^{2} = ay^{2}$.

Examining the error function expression, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm{erf}\left(x\sqrt{a} - \frac{ib}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)
= \mathrm{erf}\left(- \frac{ib}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)
= -i\,\mathrm{erfi}\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)
\tag{4}
\label{eq:4}
\end{equation}
which is a pure imaginary quantity with the assumption that all of the variables in the argument of the imaginary error function are real and $a \gt 0$. We also have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \mathrm{erf}\left(x\sqrt{a} - \frac{ib}{2\sqrt{a}}\right) = 1
\tag{5}
\label{eq:5}
\end{equation}

Using equations \eqref{eq:4} and \eqref{eq:5} in equation \eqref{eq:3} we obtain
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Re}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-a(x-ib/2a)^{2}} \mathrm{d}x \right) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\tag{6}
\label{eq:6}
\end{equation}

Combining equations \eqref{eq:6} and \eqref{eq:2} yields our final result
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}} \cos(bx) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \,\mathrm{e}^{-b^{2}/4a}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of complex analysis is as follow :

- For $z > 0$,  let $$f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{2zx}dx$$
  Complete the square $x^2-2zx= (x-z)^2 - z^2$ so that 
  $$f(z) = e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-z)^2}dx \underset{y = x-z}= e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy = Ce^{-z^2}$$
  (where $C = \sqrt{\pi}$)

Then note that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{2zx}dx$ is analytic in $z$, as well as $Ce^{-z^2}$, thus by the [identity theorem for analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \qquad f(z) = Ce^{-z^2}$$

- Apply the same trick to $$g_z(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx^2} e^{2zx}dx$$ where $s > 0$. With $y = s^{1/2}x$ we get $$g_z(s) = s^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} e^{2zs^{-1/2}y}dy = s^{-1/2}f(zs^{-1/2}) =  \frac{C}{s^{1/2}}e^{-z^2/s}$$
  Finally note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx^2} e^{2zx}dx$ is analytic in $s$ for every $s \in \mathbb{C},Re(s) > 0$, as well as $\frac{C}{s^{1/2}}e^{-z^2/s}$, thus by the identity theorem
  $$\forall s \in \mathbb{C},Re(s) > 0, \qquad g_z(s) = \frac{C}{s^{1/2}}e^{-z^2/s}$$
- Hence for any $Re(a) > 0$ :  $$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a x^2} \cos( \beta x)dx = \frac{g_{i \beta/2}(a)+g_{-i \beta/2}(a)}{4} = \frac{C}{2a^{1/2}}e^{\textstyle- \frac{\beta^2}{4a}}$$

Comment: How do you justify $$e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-z)^2}dx \underset{y = x-z}= e^{-z^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy$$ I believe you need Cauchy's Integral Theorem for this.

Comment: @robjohn no read again, I proved it for $z > 0$ (I meant $z \in \mathbb{R}$ a typo)

Comment: You've shown that $f(z)=Ce^{-z^2}$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$. How do you apply the identity theorem without showing it for $z$ in a non-empty, *open* subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @robjohn see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement

Comment: @robjohn the idea is that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z \in [a,b]$ means $f^{(k)}(a) = g^{(k)}(a)$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so they agree on an open around $a$. Otherwise, use that non-constant analytic functions have isolated zeros.

Comment: That extension of the theorem covers this. So what you really want is for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ to define $$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{2zx}\mathrm{d}x$$ Then show that for $z\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(z)=\sqrt\pi e^{-z^2}$. Then conclude that $f(z)=\sqrt\pi e^{-z^2}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @robjohn well yes, and  this is what I wrote

Comment: It's just a minor point, but you defined $f(z)$ by the integral for $z\gt0$. It might be a bit confusing for someone not familiar with this stuff.